# Including js script at end of header

Tags: javascript, child-theme

[usphilatelics.com](http://usphilatelics.com) is my first website containing javascript, and I'm having difficulty getting the script to load at the end of the page.  I originally wrote all the js within the header.php, so of course it is loaded first in the browser.  I have now copied the script into an external file, but cannot get it to load.  In functions.php I have added :

```
function wp_adding_vsb_scripts() {
//echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
wp_register_script('vsb_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-js/vsb.js', array( 'jquery'), '1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('vsb_script');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_adding_vsb_scripts' );
```

It is picking up the correct directory for the child theme I am using, but does not include the script anywhere that I can see.  What else do I need to do, where am I going wrong ?

For the time being, I have left the code in the header so that the site works.

Comment: do you have `wp_head();` in your `header.php`?

Comment: When I look at your site using google developer tools I see the js file being loaded.  The file path is:

`http://usphilatelics.com/wp-content/themes/sparkling-child/custom-js/vsb.js`

This appears to be working.  You have other jQuery issues however.

Comment: Yes, I do have wp_head(); in header.php, immediately before the </head>.

Comment: Can you clarify what jQuery issues I have ?